# do IRIs in RDF graphs need to be URL encoded?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, triplestore, iri

I am creating RDF triples/statements and I wonder if the IRIs which I use as subject, predicate, or object need to be URL encoded.

For example should the following IRI be

- `<http://example.org/instant/2015-08-12T16%3A44%3A00>`

  or
- `<http://example.org/instant/2015-08-12T16:44:00>`

This is basically a question about best practice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't need to be URL encoded, except of course for characters that are invalid in certain positions - e.g., spaces.

However different formats will have different requirements. For example, your example IRI is not valid as a property IRI for RDF/XML: property IRIS are used as XML tags and need to  be able to be written as `ns:ncname`, where ncname is a string starting with a letter or an underscore and not containing `/` or `#`. Your example has only numbers and dashes after the last `/`, so you may get a problem using it for a property.

Comment: But in cases using Wikipedia page names like `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:AB%22A%22BC` is not equal to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3AAB%22A%22BC` nor `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:AB"A"BC` while querying. This is a problem when using someone else's ontology.